# What to do when the time interval is negative? Should its magnitude only be considered or should it be rejected?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, time, velocity

Two bodies are dropped from the same point at different times. I am asked when they meet. The answer I get is -4 seconds. How do I interpret this?

I think that a *time interval* $t_2-t_1$ always has to be **positive**. But what if I get only one value of *time interval* and that value is negative ? Do I consider the magnitude or should I say the particular 'happening' for which the time interval is calculated **does not take place**?

Comment: You should say, when you come up with such situations, may be the thing is in the past?

Comment: If I am asked when do two particular bodies meet each other after they are released from different instances of time and the time interval that I calculate comes out to be negative say -4 seconds . And I am not talking about a quadratic equation. So, should I take the magnitude and say they will meet after 4 seconds or that they must have been at the same point 4 seconds earlier from the instance I considered t=0. But that ain't possible coz I released them from 0 velocity.

Comment: The bodies are separating. If you trace the trajectories backward into the past, you will find the time when they would have met. If you throw a body upward, it will rise and then fall. It is possible to arrange a trajectory that reaches its peak just when and where you released a body.

Comment: Voting to re-open. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I did another edit for clarity. Voting to reopen.

Comment: So, there is this object that I fire from a height. and when i calculate the time in which it reaches the ground i have a negative value. I dont understand how to visualize tracing back the motion to t=-bla seconds.The velocity is positive and accn is g downwards so how do i visualize it going from t=0 to t=-bla seconds.

Comment: You should edit your question so that we can all see this new information you are bringing in. And it is also exceedingly clear that you are just having a mathematical problem. Projectile problems are quadratic in time and will always give you positive and negative solutions, most often one of them is nonsense. The maths needs to give all possible solutions, regardless of sensibilities, and it comes to judgement to figure out which is sensible and which are not.

Comment: So you are saying there is no possible explanation for this negative result ? But in SHM there are cases when we can take time negative and trace the particle's motion backwards.  That's why I thought even the path of this negative result can be traced back. But I can't clearly think how it actually takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you drop the first body, it gets a head start. It moves faster than the stationary second body.

When you drop the second body, it begins to move. But its velocity is lower than the first body. You might compare the accelerations and draw a conclusion about the relative velocity between the two bodies. From this, you can conclude whether or not they will meed in the future.

Your calculation tells you that the trajectories meet at $t = -4$ sec. This is before you dropped the balls. So your calculation tells you they meet in a part of the trajectory that did not happen.

But it is possible to create another problem with extended trajectories where this does make sense.

Suppose you timed it just right at some time in the past and threw the first body upward just right. You could make it fly upward, and hit its peak at $t = 0$ just as you dropped the first body in the original problem. The trajectories past that point are the same for the two problems. You can do the same for the second body.

If you do that, it does make sense that the bodies met at $t = -4$ sec. This is no different than talking about events that occurred in the year 500 BC.

The time interval between when you launched the bodies and when they met would be positive. This indicates that meeting happened after launch.

Comment: I understand most of what you are saying now. But please bear with me...if you could take an example and show it with the values .....see the reason I m saying is suppose there is this particle launched from a height of 40 m at 20 m/s (u) under constant g downwards....and I am asked to calculate when it meets the ground ....so I get a positive and a negative result...I know my ans is the positive one...but if the (-)ve one has a meaning it would be the particle was sometime at the ground before t=0 but what I fail to understand is that how with (+) velocity it can go backwards.....

Comment: Bcoz I think if it were to start from the bottom then its initial velocity would be like suppose 40 m/s at negative time and it would decrease eventually bcoz of g downwards and get to t=0....but in the eqn s=ut+1/2at² I defined u=20 m/s and it yielded me negative....nd since t is time interval which in case of positive we calculate from t=0 to t=4....in this case we will do it from t=0 to t=-4 ....so it can't go backwards this way..because it will obviously go upwards

Comment: Wait a sec I think I get it now....when I put the value of negative time in the eqn v=u+at it gives me positive velocity hence it means it was coming to t=0 with (+)ve velocity ...since I defined it to be initial all the other points from there on are final....I get it...i think I can see it now.. thanks a lot to all of u

Answer (score 1):

If your calculation is right, it says with the given conditions they met in the past. But consider that your calculation may be wrong.

Comment: If I had to answer without taking the past into account then?  For me the incident doesn't take place after t=0. So should I say The incident never takes place ? OR I present my answer in magnitude?

Comment: You *cannot* answer it with its magnitude (if time comes out to be negative). If something occured 3 seconds before you started observing it, it is not necessary that it will occur after 3 seconds in the future